# Issue with ::before and position absolute in IE

Tags: css, element, explorer

i tried to create triangle with css and in chrome its working great
like this:

```
.custom-selectbox .x-form-trigger-default {
    background: none;
    border-width: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 23px;
}
    .custom-selectbox .x-form-trigger-default:before {
        content: "";
        border: solid #9e9e9e;
        border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 4px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: -7px;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
```

but in ie i got problem because the position:relative override the position absolute of the before element. (i see in the developer mode that its not insert new element in his parent like chrome.

what can i do?

tnx a lot

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I put your code in [a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvEpaL?editors=1100#0), but I can't see much difference between IE11 and the others.

Comment: @MrLister open the codepen in ie11 take the inspect element on the element and see that the position of the x-form-trigger-default:before is relative and not absolute.

the absolute override by the parent.

Comment: Don't believe IE webdeveloper toolbar, it "overrides" most of the css on the pseudo elements before and after but actually doesn't. Second of all, the transform: rotate(45deg) might mess with your positioning in IE, comment it out and see if it works now

Comment: @poashoas i need to believe ie webdeveloper because the triangle position in ie very far where i need him and in chrome its working great. in the webdeveloper ie when i removed the position: relative from the parent i see that he got the absolute.

Comment: and if you put a height and width 100% on it?

Comment: On my machine (Windows 8.1 64 bit), the arrowhead is in the same position in IE11 as in the other browsers. The inspector in IE acts oddly: it strikes out the properties it uses, but not the property it doesn't use. This is a bug in the inspector, but that doesn't keep the browser from displaying the page well. And it says `absolute` for the `position` property. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUkn1.jpg). If you disable the property, or change its value to `relative`, the display changes accordingly, so that's a sign it is working. I don't know what else to say.